# How to limit Spark's executor cores in RStudio?

Tags: apache-spark, rstudio, sparkr

I know if I'm using the sparkR command shell I can limit it to one executor core like this:

```
bin/sparkR --total-executor-cores 1
```

In RStudio I can successfully connect to my cluster like this:

```
sc <- sparkR.init(master="spark://<master url>")
```

I think I can pass some magic parameters there to set the number of cores, but I'm not sure how. https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/R/sparkR.init.html doesn't help much, but it has got me to this point:

```
sc <- sparkR.init("spark://<master url", "RStudio", "/spark/dir", list(total.executor.cores="1"))
```

and/or

```
sc <- sparkR.init("spark://<master url", "RStudio", "/spark/dir", list(), list(total.executor.cores="1"))
```

These successfully connects but don't limit the cores. Not sure if I have the magic property name wrong or something else?